# When did the FAI adopt the 100km line as border to space (for their purposes)?

Tags: history, altitude, karman-line

<sub>Let me preface this with a disclaimer: This is not a discussion about which height makes sense. This is purely about international recognition by the FAI.</sub>

Wikipedia says "An international committee recommended the 100 km line to the FAI, and upon adoption, it became widely accepted as the boundary to space for many purposes.", quoting [this NASA source](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/news/X-Press/stories/2005/102105_Schneider.html).

[This news article](https://www.theverge.com/2018/12/13/18130973/space-karman-line-definition-boundary-atmosphere-astronauts) says "Around 1960, the FAI decided to set the limit at 100 kilometers, just for the purpose of record setting flights — that any flight above that would be considered to be a spaceflight".

Information published by the FAI is also vague on the matter, as [this article](https://www.fai.org/page/icare-boundary) shows:

> The approved rules became Chapter 8 of the FAI Sporting Code. Naturally, they started by setting the rule that a flight could only be considered an Astronautical flight, and then qualify for a record under Chapter 8 of the FAI Sporting Code, when that flight goes beyond the 100 Km line, i.e. the Karman Line.

No mention of a date, either.

So, somewhere between the late 50s and probably the mid 60s the FAI adopted the 100km line. But when exactly? On which date was this border adopted?

<sub>A possible avenue for answering would be tracking down two 1960s editions of the FAI Sporting Code, Section 8. I wasn't able to, but the border is defined therein.</sub>